# C++ What could cause a line of code in one place to change behavior in an unrelated function?

Tags: c++, matlab, qt, matlab-compiler

Consider this mock-up of my situation.

in an external header:

```
class ThirdPartyObject
{
    ...
}
```

my code: (spread among a few headers and source files)

```
class ThirdPartyObjectWrapper
{
private:
    ThirdPartyObject myObject;
}

class Owner
{
public:
    Owner() {}
    void initialize();

private:
    ThirdPartyObjectWrapper myWrappedObject;
};

void Owner::initialize()
{
    //not weird:
    //ThirdPartyObjectWrapper testWrappedObject;

    //weird:
    //ThirdPartyObject testObject;

}
```

ThirdPartyObject is, naturally, an object defined by a third party (static precompiled) library I'm using. ThirdPartyObjectWrapper is a convenience class that eliminates a lot of boiler-plating for working with ThirdPartyObject. Owner::initialize() is called shortly *after* an instance of Owner is created.

Notice the two lines I have labeled as "weird" and "not weird" in Owner::initialize(). All I'm doing here is creating a couple of objects on the stack with their default constructors. I don't do anything with those objects and they get destroyed when they leave scope. There are no build or linker errors involved, I can uncomment either or both lines and the code will build.

However, if I uncomment "weird" then I get a segmentation fault, and (here's why I say it's weird) it's in a completely unrelated location. Not in the constructor of testObject, like you might expect, **but in the constructor of Owner::myObjectWrapper::myObject**. The weird line never even gets called, but somehow its presence or absence consistently changes the behavior of an unrelated function in a static library.

And consider that if I only uncomment "not weird" then it runs fine, executing the ThirdPartyObject constructor twice with no problems.

I've been working with C++ for a year so it's not really a surprise to me that something like this would be able happen, but I've about reached the limit of my ability to figure out *how* this gotcha is happening. I need the input of people with significantly more C++ experience than me.

**What are some possibilities that could cause this to happen? What might be going on here?**

Also, note, I'm not asking for advice on how to get rid of the segfault. Segfaults I understand, I suspect it's a simple race condition. What I don't understand is the behavior gotcha so that's the only thing I'm trying to get answers for.

My best lead is that it has to do with headers and macros. The third party library actually already has a couple of gotchas having to do with its headers and macros, for example the code won't build if you put your #include's in the wrong order. I'm not changing any #include's so strictly this still wouldn't make sense, but perhaps the compiler is optimizing includes based on the presence of a symbol here? (it would be the only mention of ThirdPartyObject in the file)

It also occurs to me that because I am using Qt, it could be that the Meta-Object Compiler (which generates supplementary code between compilations) might be involved in this. Very unlikely, as Qt has no knowledge of the third party library where the segfault is happening and this is not actually relevant to the functionality of the MOC (since at no point ThirdPartyObject is being passed as an argument), but it's worth investigating at least.

Related questions have suggested that it could be a relatively small buffer overflow or race condition that gets tripped up by compiler optimizations. Continuing to investigate but all leads are welcome.

Comment: If you suspect macro-poisoning, you could run the preprocessor and examine the code with all macros expanded. (I know gcc can do this, I don't know about your compiler.)

Comment: It's msvc at the moment, I'll look into that thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Typical culprits:

1. Some build products are stale and not binary-compatible.
2. You have a memory bug that has corrupted the state of your process, and are seeing a manifestation of that in a completely unrelated location.

Fixing #1 is trivial: delete the build folder and build again. If you're not building in a shadow build folder, you've set yourself up for failure, hopefully you now know enough to stop :)

Fixing #2 is not trivial. View manual memory management and possible buffer overflows with suspicion. Use modern C++ programming techniques to leverage the compiler to help you out: store things by value, use containers, use smart pointers, and use iterators and range-for instead of pointers. Don't use C-style arrays. Abhor C-style APIs of the `(Type * array, int count)` kind - they don't belong in C++.

Comment: Both sound relevant. 1) Certainly I've had to nuke my build folder quite a lot during this hunt, but doing it every time has shown the most consistent results. 2) The API is very much designed to be C-compatible: most of the point of ThirdPartyObjectWrapper is to use tidy containers instead of array pointers.

Answer (score 0):

What fun. I've boiled this down to the bottom.

```
//#include <otherthirdpartyheader.h>
#include <thirdpartyobject.h>

int main(...)
{
    ThirdPartyObject test;
    return 0;
}
```

This code runs. If I uncomment the first include, delete all build artifacts, and build again, then it breaks. There's obviously a header/macro component, and probably some kind of compiler-optimization component. But, get this, according to the library documentation it should give me a segfault every time because I haven't been doing a required initialization step. So the fact that it runs at all indicates unexpected behavior.

I'm chalking this up to library-specific issues rather than broad spectrum C++ issues. I'll be contacting the vendor going forward from here, but thanks everyone for the help.